# Como melhorar o processo de geração de números aleatórios não repetidos?

Tags: php

Tenho um algoritmo de criação de números randomizados para lotéricas que possuem as seguintes características:

1° Deve ser informado a quantidade de números a serem gerados.

2° Os números não podem ser repetidos.

3° Os números precisam ser em ordem crescente.

Como sou iniciante em PHP, tentei fazer "funcionar o algoritmo". Para isso, criei uma classe com uma função `geraNumeros()` de forma recursiva com o objetivo de fazer todos esses itens e me retornar um array onde ordeno utilizando o `asort()` e depois transformo em string com `implode()`. Existe alguma forma de otimizá-la ?

```
<?php

class loterias{

   public function geraNumero($aQuantidade, $aMinimo, $aMaximo) {

      $contador = 0;
      $result = array();
      while ($aQuantidade):
         $result[$aQuantidade] = str_pad(rand($aMinimo, $aMaximo), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
         $aQuantidade--;
         $contador++;
      endwhile;
      while ($contador !== count(array_unique($result))):
         $result = $this->geraNumero($contador, $aMinimo, $aMaximo);
      endwhile;
      return $result;
   }

}

// Parametros //
$quantidade = 6;
$minimo = 1;
$maximo = 60;

$mega = new loterias();
$result = $mega->geraNumero($quantidade, $minimo, $maximo);
asort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Tem alguma queixa específica? Certamente é possível otimizar, mas precisa?

Comment: pra comecar queria deixar todo o tratamento dentro da função geraNumero, usando o asort($result) antes do return e no return usar o return implode(' - ',$result); pra sair uma string, acontece que, quando o um dos valores deste array repete e entra no segundo while e gera novos  numeros não repetidos, quando ele vai pro return ele volta no asort e pega os numeros repetidos. nao entendi o porque ai tive que fazer o tratamento por fora da função, e também to achando ela lenta...

Comment: Outra coisa: precisa ser recursiva?

Comment: eu não consegui fazer sem ser recursiva...

Comment: Dê uma olhada nestas questões, veja se alguma serve: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fisher+yates - fisher-yates é adequado para loteria, você embaralha o set de números e pega quantos forem necessários.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com algumas funções para arrays consegui o mesmo resultado, segue explicação do que faz cada função:

[`range()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) - Cria um array a partir de um mínimo e máximo.

[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-rand.php) - Retorna aleatoriamente uma chave de um array. Com o segundo parâmetro é possível  especificar o número de elementos que você quer retornar.

[`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-flip.php) - Inverte o valor com a chave de um array. Fiz isso pois no PHP as chaves se iniciam com zero, e acho que as loterias não começam com zero.

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) - Para cada elemento de um array, executa uma determinada função, no caso seria o `str_pad` com os parâmetros necessários.

```
<?php

function geraNumeros($quantidade, $minimo, $maximo)
{
    $listaDeNumeros = range($minimo, $maximo);
    $numeros = array_rand(array_flip($listaDeNumeros), $quantidade);

    $numeros = array_map(function($value){
        return str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);   
    }, $numeros);

    return implode($numeros, ',');
}

echo geraNumeros(6, 1, 60) . PHP_EOL;
echo geraNumeros(6, 1, 60) . PHP_EOL;
echo geraNumeros(6, 1, 60) . PHP_EOL;
echo geraNumeros(6, 1, 60) . PHP_EOL;
```

[Exemplo no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/AUukjt)

Comment: testei sua solução e esta de parabéns, mesmas funcionalidades mais performance. seria possivel colocar o str_pad para acrescentar '0' nos números que só possuem 1 caractere? ficando 01 - 05 ...

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues complementei com um array_map

Comment: engraçado, testei a solução do array_map no php 5.2 e não deu certo, agora testei na ultima versão 5.6.4 e deu certo, vi a documentação do php array_map e ela esta disponivel apartir do 4,   existe algum modulo/restrição que tenha que habilitar para funcionar ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não funcionou por causa das closures, ou funções anonimas, a parte do `function()`. Se realmente precisa do código rodando no PHP 5.2, troque o array_map por um loop.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php      Nota: Funções anonimas estão disponíveis desde PHP 5.3.0.    entendi. vou fazer um loop então.

Answer (score 4):

Deixo uma solução que, na minha opinião, tem um código simples:

```
<?php

class loterias{

   public function geraNumero($aQuantidade, $aMinimo, $aMaximo) {
       if( $aQuantidade > ($aMaximo - $aMinimo) ) {
           return false;
       }

       $numeros = range($aMinimo, $aMaximo);
       shuffle($numeros);
       array_splice($numeros, 0, $aQuantidade);
       sort($numeros);
       return $numeros;
   }

}
```

Os requisitos não podem ser satisfeitos se a diferença entre o máximo e mínimo forem menores do que a quantidade, por isso fiz essa validação (poderia ter lançado uma exceção).

- É criado um array com todos os números possíveis.
- Depois são baralhados com com a função "shuffle".
- São escolhidos os primeiros na quantidade especificada.
- São ordenados.