# Função com in_array não está funcionando

Tags: php

Tenho esta função que não está funcionando o in_array como deveria

```
function genNumeros($min, $max, $quantity, $qtd, $somamin = false, $somamax = false)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) {
        $numbers = range($min, $max);
        shuffle($numbers);
        $a = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
        asort($a);

        $x = array(14, 17);

        if (in_array($x, $a)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($somamin) {
            if (array_sum($a) < $somamin)
                continue;   
        }

        if ($somamax) {
            if (array_sum($a) > $somamax)
                continue;   
        }

        foreach ($a as $key => $o) {
            if (end(array_keys($a)) == $key) {
                $aux = '';
            } else {
                $aux = ' - ';
            }

            echo $o . $aux;    
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Somente está funcionando se eu utilizar dessa maneira:

```
    if (in_array(14, $a)) {
       continue;
    }
```

Exemplo:

```
<?= genNumbers(1, 25, 15, 100, 201, 201) ?>
```

Este exemplo continua retornando valores com 14 e 17 (que não eram para aparecer):

- 2 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 9 - 11 - 13 - 14 - 16 - 17 - 18 - 19 - 21 - 22 - 25
- 1 - 3 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 11 - 13 - 15 - 17 - 18 - 20 - 21 - 22 - 23 - 25
- 1 - 3 - 5 - 6 - 8 - 11 - 12 - 15 - 17 - 19 - 20 - 21 - 22 - 24 - 25
- 2 - 3 - 5 - 8 - 10 - 12 - 15 - 16 - 18 - 19 - 20 - 22 - 23 - 24 - 25
- 3 - 4 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 17 - 20 - 21 - 23 - 24 - 25

O que há de errado?

Comment: Você está tentando localizar array( 14, 17), e não 14 e 17 separadamente. Nâo seria isso que você está procurando? `if ( in_array(14, $a) || in_array( 17, $a ) ) {
            continue;
        }`

Comment: Assim eu sei que funciona, já tinha testado aqui.
Mas não é escalável dessa forma. Caso eu precise de 5 números? 10? E irei usar isso na função de alguma forma, tipo `genNumbers(1, 25, 15, 100, 201, 201, array(14, 17, 5, 2))` (algo assim).  Por isso estou nesse dilema :s

Comment: @thiago você esta desenvolvendo esse genNumbers para jogos  de loteria?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues estou sim, porque? ;)

Comment: @thiago da uma olhada nesta minha pergunta :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46248/como-melhorar-o-processo-de-gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-n%C3%A3o-repetidos

Answer (score 0):

A função in_array não espera receber dois arrays, você pode criar uma função para fazer essa verificação.

Essa função abaixo retorna `true` se qualquer conteúdo do `$array1` existir dentro de `$array2`. Não entendi bem sua lógica na pergunta, mas acredito que se não for exatamente isso que você quer então é questão de adaptar pouca coisa para o resultado desejado.

```
function VerificaConteudoArray($array1, $array2) {
    foreach ($array1 as $inner) {
        if (in_array($inner,$array2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Fazendo uma função dessa então você só trocaria uma linha no seu código, onde usa o `in_array` chama a nova função. Ficaria assim:

```
<?php


genNumeros(10,20,5,6);


function genNumeros($min, $max, $quantity, $qtd, $somamin = false, $somamax = false)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) {
        $numbers = range($min, $max);
        shuffle($numbers);
        $a = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
        asort($a);

        $x = array(14, 17);

        if (VerificaConteudoArray($x, $a)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($somamin) {
            if (array_sum($a) < $somamin)
                continue;   
        }

        if ($somamax) {
            if (array_sum($a) > $somamax)
                continue;   
        }

        foreach ($a as $key => $o) {
            if (end(array_keys($a)) == $key) {
                $aux = '';
            } else {
                $aux = ' - ';
            }

            echo $o . $aux;    
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
}



function VerificaConteudoArray($array1, $array2) {

    foreach ($array1 as $inner) {
        if (in_array($inner,$array2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Aqui tem um [Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0jkj-7d5i) com esse código rodando. Rodado no Fiddle o 14 e 17 não aparecem.

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro parâmetro deve ser o valor a ser procurado, e o segundo parâmetro é o array em si. `in_array('valor', array('valor', 'valor1', '...'))`. Veja que você está passando o array no primeiro parâmetro: `$x = array(14, 17);`. Na sua lógica, se for para procurar dentro do seu array `$x` cada elemento do array `$a`, você deveria testar cada posição: `$x[0]` e `$x[1]` para o seu array `$a`: `in_array($x[0], $a)` e `in_array($x[1], $a)`.

Assim deve resolver o problema:

```
function genNumeros($min, $max, $quantity, $qtd, $somamin = false, $somamax = false)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) {
        $numbers = range($min, $max);
        shuffle($numbers);
        $a = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
        asort($a);

        $x = array(14, 17);

        if (in_array($x[0], $a) && in_array($x[1], $a)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($somamin) {
            if (array_sum($a) < $somamin)
                continue;   
        }

        if ($somamax) {
            if (array_sum($a) > $somamax)
                continue;   
        }

        foreach ($a as $key => $o) {
            if (end(array_keys($a)) == $key) {
                $aux = '';
            } else {
                $aux = ' - ';
            }

            echo $o . $aux;    
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Mas se deseja fazer esses valores dinâmicos, recomendo que você crie um método para isso:

```
 function genNumeros($min, $max, $quantity, $qtd, $somamin = false, $somamax = false)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) {
            $numbers = range($min, $max);
            shuffle($numbers);
            $a = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
            asort($a);

            $x = array(14, 17);

            if (continueInArray($x, $a)) {
               continue;
            }

            if ($somamin) {
                if (array_sum($a) < $somamin)
                    continue;   
            }

            if ($somamax) {
                if (array_sum($a) > $somamax)
                    continue;   
            }

            foreach ($a as $key => $o) {
                if (end(array_keys($a)) == $key) {
                    $aux = '';
                } else {
                    $aux = ' - ';
                }

                echo $o . $aux;    
            }
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

function continueInArray($a, $b) {
    if (is_array($a)) {
        if (count($a)) {
           foreach ($a as $value) {
              return in_array($value, $b);
           }
        }
    } else {
       return in_array($a, $b);
    }
    return false;
}
```